# what does Threshold means in php code

Tags: php

Can someone help me what does "**Threshold**" means in PHP code.
The code goes like this hereunder:

```
function IsRequestLocked($request_date, $status=0){

   $retval = true;

   if($status==0){

    $current_date = mktime(23, 59, 59, intval(date("n")),
        intval(date("j")), intval(date("Y"))); 

    if($this->Threshold['THRESHOLD_TYPE']){ 
        $request_date = mktime(23, 59, 59, 
        intval(date("n", $request_date)), 
        intval(date("j",$request_date)) + intval($this->Threshold['THRESHOLD']), 
        intval(date("Y",$request_date))); 
     }else{
        $request_date = mktime(23, 59, 59, 
        intval(date("n", $request_date)), 
        intval(date("j",$request_date)) - intval($this->Threshold['THRESHOLD']), 
        intval(date("Y",$request_date))); 
     }
   $retval = ($current_date > $request_date);       
   }
   return $retval;
}
```

Comment: Give us the class definition of `$this`. As it stands now, this is not capable of being answered

Comment: "Threshold" just means a tipping point in some calculation. [wiktionary: point at which an action is triggered](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/threshold). In this case it seems to vary on two divergent algorithms to detect a timed event.

Answer (score 10):

A threshold in PHP means the same as it does in English: a limit beyond which something changes.

Classical sense, the threshold of your water tank is where the overflow tube is. If the water gets to that level, it will flow out of the tank rather than continuing to fill it.

Computer-related: the threshold of your server room is about 30 degrees Celsius. Beyond that, alarms should start going 'Whoop Whoop' and someone had better check out the aircon.

Or, if the requests to a web server farm start banking up, another instance of the server is bought online to hopefully help out (capacity on demand).

In your particular case, the code is simply adding or subtracting a threshold depending on its type and comparing it to the current date. Beyond that, I can't give much more since I have no further information about your application.

---

Based on the names of functions and variables, my best bet would be that requests can either be locked for a certain time before their request date or a certain time after. An example of the former may be an appointment with a customer. Once it gets within (e.g.) two days, you're not allowed to change the date of the appointment, lest you invoke the wrath of said customer.

For the latter, maybe once a request to change a password has been enacted, the request must stay around for five days (but be non-editable) to ensure the user doesn't change the pasword to often.

Fairly contrived examples, I'll admit, but since I know little of your application, it's the best I could do.

Comment: I am very much thankful to your answer pax, which very well explained to me.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't mean anything special in PHP. That is an array that belongs to some class (that has your `IsRequestLocked()` method), that I can't identify from your current code.

You need to at least tell us what class this is and where you got it from, otherwise we can only give very general answers.

Answer (score 1):

The example you are showing it's a variable inside your object, an array to be precise. So it could mean a lot of things.

Since there is some date time involved, I would say it as something to do with some expiration.

Answer (score 1):

If I was to make a wild guess, I would say `Threshold['THRESHOLD']` is some kind of minutes or seconds a resource is to remain locked and `Threshold['THRESHOLD_TYPE']` is different kinds of locks with different lock times.

Comment: "Days", I would suspect, since it's being added to the `j` member (day of month). But, other than that, I think you're right.